# chrome extension to automatically turn all flash to low-res?

Tags: flash, google-chrome-extensions

Is there any chrome extension to automatically turn all flash to low-resolution when opening a webpage? I would like to be able to use pages with flash but have it low-resolution by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flash render quality](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bbkhhhlbomjpenealmjakmfmlgnbimep) is the extension you seek.